# How to display hundreds of plots neatly in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, plot, r-markdown

I have a loop code that generate 100 different plots from a subset of a data. The simplified version of the code is as follow:-

```
for (i in 1:100) {
  df <- alldata[alldata$id==i,]
  plot(df)
}
```

The problem is I need to use R markdown to display the results. However, in the above code, the 100 plots will be display one after another in long pages, which will be very untidy.

I would like to display one plot at a time, but allow the viewer to click on the 'next page' to see the next plot.  Is it possible to do so in R markdown?

Thanks and sorry if my question is too easy, as I am completely new to this (first time coding).

Comment: Sample desired output of the 100 plots: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mPQ2H.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try my approach. I used  `html_document` and tabsets ... works fine for my needs.

````
---
title: "Plot in loops"
output: html_document
---

# Title {.tabset .tabset-fade}

```{r, results='asis'}
for (i in 1:100) {
  df <- data.frame(
    x = 1:100,
    y = runif(100)
  )

  cat( paste('## title no.', i, '\n' ) )
  plot(df)
  cat('\n \n')
}
```
````

Comment: Thanks @J_F. This is exactly what I want!